# Powershell - Set-Acl using lines from a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set permissions to a few thousand subfolders with this structure:

- G:\Jobs\10\100001\Subfolder1
- G:\Jobs\10\100002\Subfolder1
- G:\Jobs\10\100003\Subfolder1
- G:\Jobs\10\100004\Subfolder1

I've created a txt file and have the full path as above on each line and I have used:

Get-Acl G:\PermissionTemplate | Set-Acl 'G:\Jobs\10\100001\Subfolder1'

This works perfectly, does exactly what I need. Problem is the other 3478 folders I need to modify. PS is not my strong-point and I'm really struggling to get anything like, Get-Content or ForEach-Object etc to do anything.

A huge virtual high-5 and virtual chocolate fish for anyone who can help me out :)

Cheers!

Comment: If the folders are in the same Directory you can try: `foreach ($Folder in $(Get-ChildItem -Directory \\GDrive\Jobs\10 -Depth 2)) {
    $Acl=Get-Acl $Folder.FullName
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Rule)
    Set-Acl $folder.Fullname $Acl
}` where `$Rule` would be the access rule.

Comment: Thanks Abraham, are you able to dumb down the statement:
"where $Rule would be the access rule."?

Comment: That would be your permissions (*rules*): `Get-Acl G:\PermissionTemplate` so you'd just set that to the variable `$Rule`. If that makes sense(:

Comment: It doesn't but I'll continue to try and figure it out! Really appreciate the quick response. I've run out of time today but will get back to it first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Assuming that "*I've created a txt file*" is called `.\Folders.txt`, the command would be: `Get-Content .\Folders.txt |ForEach-Object { Get-Acl G:\PermissionTemplate | Set-Acl $_ }`

Comment: Thanks iRon, that looks like what I'm after. Although I am getting: Set-Acl : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string. Do I not need to define each line of the txt file as $dir or something like that? 

I'll keep at it, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: A little progress, the script now goes like this:

$DestDir = Get-ChildItem 'G:\Data\Jobs\10' -Filter 'Subfolder1' -Recurse -Depth 2 |
ForEach-Object { Get-Acl 'G:\Data\Jobs\10\PermTemp'| Set-Acl '$DestDir' }

Seems like this one is just about there but I get an error with Set-Acl 'Path' is null. So I'm guessing I'm not using or setting the variable correctly